# Can't run Android application in release build

Tags: android, apk, proguard

My Android app is working fine if it's launched from android studio to an emulator or real device , but now i want build a signed apk , once it's generated i intall it but app crashes when launched.
i got this error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application myPackage.app.AppController: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "myPackage.app.AppController" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data...
```

build.gradle :

```
            apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
        apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

        android {
            buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
            compileOptions {
                sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
                targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            }
            compileSdkVersion 28
            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "my.app.id"
                minSdkVersion 21
                targetSdkVersion 28
                multiDexEnabled true
                versionCode 9
                versionName "9"
                testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            }
            buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled true
                    shrinkResources true
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                    //signingConfig signingConfigs.configSigned
                }
            }......
```

proguard-rules.pro :

```
-ignorewarnings
-obfuscationdictionary windows.txt
-classobfuscationdictionary windows.txt
-keep class android.support.v7.internal.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.internal.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep class dgsn.gov.ma.dgsn.model.** { *; }
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
```

Comment: try to build it with `minifyEnabled false`, if it builds then your proguard rules are wrong

Comment: thx , it's workign , i also removed shrinnking ressources.

Comment: if you want to move that to production, then you need to correct the proguard files, don't deploy it without minify and shrinking

Answer (score 0):

you need add some code progaurd rules to project 
your progaurd is wrong and some code missed 
for example if you are using retrofit 
you must add progaurd rules about retrofit
you need check about depency in gradle.build and you must check about progaurd rules .